# Send a json on a post request with HttpClient and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, request, httpclient

I have a problem with this code, my goal is to send a modification via an API so I'm doing a `request` over `HttpClient`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

public class patchticket
{
   public string patch(string ticketid)
   {

       using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
       {
           using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), "https://desk.zoho.com/api/v1/tickets/"+ticketid))
           {
               request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "6af7d2d213a3ba5e9bc64b80e02b000");
               request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("OrgId", "671437200");

               request.Content = new StringContent("{\"priority\" : \"High\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


               var response =  httpClient.SendAsync(request);
           return response

           }
       }

   }
}
```

The result is that I don't have any error, but changes doesn't take effect.

The credentials are okay, I have tested it with curl with the same parameters and it works great.

Comment: Don't you mean "PATCH" instead of "PATH"? Also, you now need to change your API credentials as you've exposed them here.

Comment: Yes sry it's PATCH, those credentials are false ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you want to post a `json` in the request. Try to define the right content-type that is `application/json`. For sample:

```
request.Content = new StringContent("{\"priority\" : \"High\"}",
                                    Encoding.UTF8, 
                                    "application/json");
```

Since your method returns a `string` it can be a a non-async method. The method `SendAsync` is async and you have to wait the request finished. You could try to call `Result` after the request. For sample:

```
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
return response.Content; // string content
```

And you will get an object of [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netframework-4.8). There are a lot of useful information about the response on it.

Anyway, since it's an IO bound operation, it's better to use the async version like this:

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
return response.Content; // string content
```

Comment: Okey, i try tomorrow thanks, you only think that's that the problem ? Before i was using `var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);` but i have an error with the await , it says me that i cannot use it, you know why ?

Comment: Okey, i try tomorrow :)