# how to convert WebClient Post method to HttpClient in .net 6.0

Tags: c#, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am upgrading a solution from .net core to .net 6.0 where i want to convert WebClient post method to
HttpClient.Here is WebClient Post Code

request contains username and password

```
request= new
            {
                OsUsername = "abc",
                OsPassword = "password"
            }
private JObject Post(string path, object request)
    {
        string rawRequest = null;
        string rawResponse = null;

        try
        {
            using var client = new WebClient();
            rawRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, (Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting) Formatting.Indented);
            rawResponse = client.UploadString(BaseUrl + path, "POST", rawRequest);

            var response = JObject.Parse(rawResponse);

            if (!path.StartsWith("resource"))
            {
                ValidateResponse(response);
            }

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Logger.Information(rawRequest);
            Logger.Error(rawResponse);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

i am writing following code and using HttpClient Post method

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("BaseUrl");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", "abc"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "password")
            });
            var result = await client.PostAsync(BaseUrl + url, content);
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
        }
```

but not getting weather above code is correct and also can i use send method instead of postasync method please suggest.

Comment: Your request body in the first one will look like `{"OsUsername":"abc","OsPassword":"password"}` (because it's JSON), whereas the request body in the second one looks like `Username=abc&Password=password` (form body).  Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329843/send-a-json-on-a-post-request-with-httpclient-and-c-sharp) can help you correct the second code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object of parameters like that instead of `KeyValuePair`

```cs
internal record User(string Name, string Password);
```

Then you can use a generic method

```cs
public async Task<TResult> Post<TResult>(string url, object data)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var content = JsonContent.Create(data);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(result);
}
```

Example of using:

```cs
var user = new User("abc", "password");
var result = await Post<Result>("https://url.com/", user);
```